Euclid’s “Elements” Redux Callahan's Problem 5
I'm working through Euclid's “Elements” Redux by Callahan (The 13 June 2024 edition), but I have a problem understanding the exercise instructions. This time is one on page 107, specifically the number 17. The problem says:


If perpendiculars fall on the sides of a polygon from any point and if we divide
each side into two segments, then the sum of the squares on one set of alternate
segments is equal to the sum of the squares on the remaining set.


I don't understand exactly why I need to do. In my understanding, I need to divide the sides of a polygon with a perpendicular. The next thing is to build a square on these segments and after that, I have to show that the sum of the squares on alternate sides is equal to the sum of the remaining ones. I made the next diagram:

So, the sum of the orange squares is equal to the sum of the purple squares. I want to know if I'm right. As for the proof, I want to try first. If I'm not right. Please let me know.
It is difficult for me to understand some instructions, since English is not my first language.

Begin with convex quadrilaterals, like a triangle, and take any interior point, then drop perpendiculars from that point onto each side so they are each divided into two segments. Then, traveling around the polygon, compare the sum of alternating squares (i.e., on even vs odd segments).

Thanks! I understand now.

Convex polygons rather, but you get it.
